# JBoss Modules: how to run service from module?

Tags: java, jboss-modules

I'm trying to run a service from the module but next error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.example.prototype.api.Service: Provider com.example.prototype.foo.FooService not a subtype
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
        at com.example.prototype.api.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

**Approach and architecture description:**
I would like to have an application with modules where one module describes interfaces and another implements it.  The idea is that the interface module shouldn't know anything about concrete implementation.
**The codebase** is located [on github](https://github.com/bullet-tooth/jboss-modules-prototype).

**Notes:**
`api-module` has a `Service` interface. Also, it has `Main` class that instantiates `foo-module` with calling service implementation.
`foo-module` has the implementation of the `Service` interface.

API-module Main class:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    File root = new File("prototype");

    ModuleLoader loader = new ModuleLoader(new LocalModuleFinder(new File[]{root}));
    Module module = loader.loadModule("com.example.prototype.foo");
    ServiceLoader<Service> services = module.loadService(Service.class);

    System.out.println("Foo Service loaded");
    services.forEach(Service::sayWhatsup);
    System.out.println("Done!");
  }

}
```

Foo module `module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.8" name="com.example.prototype.foo" version="1.0">
  <main-class name="com.example.prototype.foo.Main"/>
  <resources>
    <artifact name="com.example.prototype:foo-module:1.0"/>
  </resources>

  <dependencies>
    <module name="com.example.prototype.api"/>
  </dependencies>

  <provides>
    <service name="com.example.prototype.api.Service">
      <with-class name="com.example.prototype.foo.FooService"/>
    </service>
  </provides>

</module>
```

As far as I understand `Service.class` and `FooService` have different class loaders and that's because the class compatibility issue appears.

Please help to solve this. Thanks in advance!